# Want to create a separate theme apk for my application in android

Tags: android, integration, android-theme

How to develop an application for my previous application just plug and play type. Like i have an application and want its theme application for that now. Please help me how can i do this kind of stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your theme app by storing your resources for your theme (Styles, images, colors, ...). 
Then in your application, you can access the resources of another app using the following code :

```
Resources res = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("com.example.foo")
```